# Find missing dates

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to write a function which can find the missing dates in a dataframe.

This is my scenario:
(Data is sorted by customer and then by from date.
 Date format is : M/D/Y)

```
From Date   To Date
Customer        
A   1/10/2017   2/9/2017
A   NaN         NaN
A   3/10/2017   4/9/2017
A   NaN         NaN
A   4/9/2017    5/9/2017
B   2/10/2017   3/9/2017
B   NaN         NaN
B   3/9/2017    4/9/2017
```

The function should read on From Date and To Date and see if there is continuity on the dates(for each customer).Than, add a column(Results) and show the results.

The function has to iterates on each customer.

**(Added comment)**

*Please take a look at my expected output. I am adding indexes and some explanations too:
Index[1] shows missing because the continuity is broken, you can come to this conclusion by comparing To date[0] vs. From date[2], those two value are not the same. On the other hand: To date[2]= From date[4] this is why “Results” shows Not Missing[3].*

```
Customer From date  To date Results
0   A   1/10/2017   2/9/2017    NaN
1   A   NaN         NaN         Missing
2   A   3/10/2017   4/9/2017    NaN
3   A   NaN         NaN         Not Missing
4   A   4/9/2017    5/9/2017    NaN
5   B   2/10/2017   3/9/2017    NaN
6   B   NaN         NaN         Not Missing
7   B   3/9/2017    4/9/2017    NaN
```

Any help will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Can you post this `df.to_dict()` ?

Comment: Do you want to check for rows that are missing both dates or either one of them? Also, you can't find the missing dates as they do not exist in the first place. You'll only be getting the index of that row, which is Customer in your case I believe

Comment: In my scenario, if from date is missing, to date is missing too.
I don’t need to know the index. My idea is to append a new column that says: missing or not missing. 
If you can see closer, you will notice that, the first NaN is”really” missing, the other two are not missing.(I know, it sounds confusing, sorry) 
Actually this is a report writing error which I am trying to fix it.

Comment: @RafaelC not sure of how to do that but I can send the CSV file.Does that work for you? Thank you!

Comment: @RafaelC this is how it looks like: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t0AS1psG8QsTn1ppPGShpGikvDRKP3xy#scrollTo=GeaUbsKMDVpY

Comment: @Chris thank you for your advice. I just did it. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Chris Yes it is correct. 
As you can see on index[5], it is another customer(B), with that said the iteration should start from the beginning. 
It doesn’t mean that the customer(A) has  2/9/2017 on To date, and this date should be on customer(B) too. Different customers show different habits.
Please let me know if this make sense.

Comment: @Chris In my scenario, I can't change the dates(I have millions). What I am trying to  accomplish is this: Write a function that reads on From Date and To Date and see if there is continuity on the dates(by using the login described on the post), for each customer.Than, add a column(Results) and show the results

Comment: @Chris Sorry for the confusion are you asking for index[3] or index[4]?

Comment: @Chris Also just to clarify: the format is: M/D/Y

Comment: @Verbamore Updated my answer to reflect all the information :)

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much for your help. We are almost there. I have two last questions for you: How can I change the header of the added column. It says "To Date"? Also is it possible to add some comments( if you can). I am new in python and I have some difficulties to understand your logic. Thank you again!

Comment: @Verbamore Happy to help. I've added how to change the column name. I'll add the detailed explanation tomorrow if its okay with you.

Comment: @Chris that works. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Verbamore I've added line-by-line explanation. Hope it can help you better understand the answer :)

Comment: @Chris Hello Chris. did you had a chance to look at my new question? Looking forward to read your answer/advice. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.groupby` with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['From Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df['To Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['To Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")

dfs = []
for k, d in df.groupby('Customer'):
    dt = d.dropna()['To Date'].shift(1)[1:]
    res = []
    for i in range(dt.shape[0]):
        if (d['From Date'][dt.index] == dt).iloc[i]:
            res.append('Not Missing')
        else:
            res.append('Missing')
    for i in range(dt.shape[0]):
        dt.iloc[i] = res[i]
    dt.index -= 1
    dfs.append(pd.concat([d, dt], 1))
result = pd.concat(dfs)
print(result)

  Customer  From Date    To Date      To Date
0        A 2017-01-10 2017-02-09          NaN
1        A        NaT        NaT      Missing
2        A 2017-03-10 2017-04-09          NaN
3        A        NaT        NaT  Not Missing
4        A 2017-04-09 2017-05-09          NaN
5        B 2017-02-10 2017-03-09          NaN
6        B        NaT        NaT  Not Missing
7        B 2017-03-09 2017-04-09          NaN
```

And finally:

```
df.columns = ['From Date', 'To Date', 'Results']
print(df)

  Customer  From Date    To Date      Results
0        A 2017-01-10 2017-02-09          NaN
1        A        NaT        NaT      Missing
2        A 2017-03-10 2017-04-09          NaN
3        A        NaT        NaT  Not Missing
4        A 2017-04-09 2017-05-09          NaN
5        B 2017-02-10 2017-03-09          NaN
6        B        NaT        NaT  Not Missing
7        B 2017-03-09 2017-04-09          NaN
```

Explanations:

- `pd.to_datetime`: This is to convert your looking-like-dates data to actual datetime data. In this way, `pandas` can do some calculations (e.g. `diff` between two days). Since it is a serial operation, must be done on each desired column rather than on the entire dataframe.
- `df.groupby`: `groupby` returns a dict-like object with given condition as key. Since the whole calculation was to be done on **each** `Customer`, used `df.groupby('Customer').
- `dt = d.dropna()['To Date'].shift(1)[1:]`: `d` is the subset of dataframe that only contains single `Customer`'s data. `shift(1)` provides dataframe shifted 1 cell below. This is to make comparison between `To Date` and `From Date` easy.
- `d['From Date'][dt.index] == dt`: Provides boolean result of comparison between the `To Date` and `From Date`.
- `dt.iloc[i] = res[i]`: Once you have a `list` of Missing's and Not Missing's, you assign it back to `dt` to make `Results` columns.
- `dfs.append(pd.concat([d, dt] 1))`: concatenate newly made `Results` column with original `d`, and `append` it to a `list`
- `result = pd.concat(dfs)`: `dfs` now contains subset dataframes of each `Customer`. Concatenate them into a single big dataframe.
- `result.columns = ['To Date', 'From Date', 'Results']`: Reassign column names.

Comment: I am having an error, when I run your script. Any idea what could it be: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SWZLcz2_3810r5cO5zbFIkP8viT0N7b9#scrollTo=_3YCjuT3BITp

Comment: Your example data has From Date and To Date whereas real data has From date and To date. Lowering Date to date will do the job ;)

Comment: thank you so much. I have one last question How can I change the header of the added column. It says "To Date"? Also is it possible to add some comments( if you can)

Comment: thank you so much for your help. your comments are very helpful, now I have a better understanding of the script. For the last 2-3 days I have been running the script to my reports and 90% of times I got the expected results. I have identified some cases when the script is facing difficulties( specifically, multiple dates in one cells). I think I know what the solution could be and I need some advices from(if that is possible). if you can, do you want me to edit this question or write a new one?

Comment: @Verbamore I’m so glad the answer helped you greatly :). For you new question, it is not recommended to edit a question that already has an accepted answer. You can post a new question, and leave me a link in this comment, so I or others can help you ;)

Comment: this is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953030/report-correction-missing-dates Please let me know if it makes sense.Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hello Chris. did you had a chance to look at my new question? Looking forward to read your answer/advice. thank you!